# Почему из видов доступны все проекты решения asp.net mvc?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, проект

Всем привет. В моем решении есть несколько проектов: DAL, BLL, ViewModels, Entities и сам проект сайта. Так вот, из проекта сайта есть ссылка на ViewModels. По непонятной причине при использовании модели для вида, из вида есть доступ к проектам решения и получается конфликт между ссылкой и проектом. Из этого получаются другие аномалии, как невалидация полей модели и возможно другие. Что делать, как быть и как это работает?[image: project_error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Скорее всего в сборке ViewModels 2 раза создан класс модели.
2. Если сборка компилируется, значит неправильно разрешены namespaces. Есть 2 варинта: убрать один из глобальных неймспейсов в web.config или на view использовать директиву @using. Однако, первый вариант наиболее предсказуемый.

Comment: Спасибо. Добавил @using в вид и проблема исчезла. Правда побочные проблемы с невалидацией остались, но видимо тут другая причина. Кстати класс был создан единожды.